# Order by clause on max numbers in sql

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have two columns in a table. The first column is defined as ActivityName and the second column as ListOrder. Data contains 5 rows as shown in table in the picture. I'm applying order by query on ListOrder column in ascending order to display ActivityName. However it's not generating the expected result. When i gave number in order wise, like 12345, it worked. How can i apply order by clause in such case.

Below is my query

```
  Select ActivityName from dbo.StudentActivity Order by ListOrder asc
```

[image]

Comment: what is the datatype of ListOrder Field

Comment: What do you mean by “when I gave number in order wise, like 12345, it worked”?

Comment: Its varchar(250)

Comment: @BrienFoss. It means when used 1 for Confirmation Email, 2 for WhatsApp group, 3 for Student Card .... It worked on that case.

Comment: Select ActivityName from dbo.StudentActivity Order by CAST(ListOrder AS INT) asc

Comment: If the `ListOrder` column contains **numerical** values - ***why*** is it a `varchar(250)` ?!?!? Doesn't make any sense - any doesn't make it easy to sort on it, either. If it's numerical - it **should be** a numerical datatype - either `INT` if you have only whole numbers, or else `DECIMAL(p,s)` if you need fractions

Comment: JazakAllah @HaziqAhmed

Comment: Glad it helped!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try by parsing "ListOrder" like below:

```
SELECT ActivityName FROM dbo.StudentActivity ORDER BY CAST(ListOrder AS INT) ASC
```